# Open pdf,txt,doc,jpg etc files in a popup using jQuery and coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am working on a small project and I have a file links to download from server. However, instead of downloading the file I want them open in fixed size pop up. I tried facebox but facebox(http://defunkt.io/facebox/) fail to display pdf files and other text files. any one have any idea what I suppose to do in order to accomplish this task.
Thanks you

Comment: I do not have time to write a proper answer, but .. you cannot display multiple content-types ie `text/html` and `application/pdf` within the same browser window.  However, you can *embed* different content, within the HTML, using the `<object>` tag. The only other option is to open a new browser window (or use an `iframe`). Keep in mind you cannot *force* the browser to open the files. It will open them if, and only if, it is configured to do so. Otherwise, it will prompt the user to download.

Comment: @Leigh is correct. I have written some code that opens a jQueryUI dialog box that contains an iframe that shows a PDF. It works but it still depends on the user's browser settings if the PDF shows there or not. By default it prompts to open or save the file.